# Pandas, find each instance of a string appearing in particular column

Tags: python, pandas

As the title implies, I'm trying to find each occurrence of the string "BUY" in a pandas dataframe and get a slice of data from this part. Here is a shortened version (and simplified) of my dataframe:

|  | Time | Price | MA | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1:00 | 33 | 34 | BUY |
| 1 | 1:01 | 35 | 36 | BUY |
| 2 | 1:02 | 34 | 35 | BUY |
| 3 | 1:03 | 35 | 33 | SELL |

What I want to do is find the 3 lines after each time BUY occurs and then be able to get the data from there. e.g.:

**First instance:**

|  | Time | Price | MA | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1:00 | 33 | 34 | BUY |
| 1 | 1:01 | 35 | 36 | BUY |
| 2 | 1:02 | 34 | 35 | BUY |

**Second instance:**

|  | Time | Price | MA | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1:01 | 35 | 36 | BUY |
| 2 | 1:02 | 34 | 35 | BUY |
| 3 | 1:03 | 35 | 33 | SELL |

And so on...

the idea is to then compare the individual values like the price and MA from this slice of data I create.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rolling the dataframe

```py
out = [window for window in df.rolling(window=3)
       if len(window) == 3 and window['Action'].iloc[0] == 'BUY']
```

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)

[   Time  Price  MA Action
0  1:00     33  34    BUY
1  1:01     35  36    BUY
2  1:02     34  35    BUY,
    Time  Price  MA Action
1  1:01     35  36    BUY
2  1:02     34  35    BUY
3  1:03     35  33   SELL]
```

Comment: Do you have a recommended way for accessing the data within each of these tables? I'm not that familar with using the rolling method

Comment: @LaMyass Not user what you want, but each `window` object is a DataFrame, you can assess it like `window['Time']` etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Where would I place window['Time'] in order to access each dataframe?

Comment: @LaMyass Don't quite understand what you want. But you can do something like `[window['Time'] for window in df.rolling(window=3)]`

Comment: My goal is to take the price at the beginning of the dataframe (33) and then subtract it from the price at the end of that data frame (34) for each dataframe

Comment: @LaMyass Not sure what does dataframe (33) mean, but you can do something like `window['Price'].iloc[0]` to get the the price at the beginning of a `window` object and `window['Price'].iloc[-1]` to get the end.